# Writing query to substract shows error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am using sqlCE, I wrote the following query

```
SELECT        Stocks - @Stocks AS Qty
FROM            ItemInventoryControl
WHERE        (ItemName = @ItemName)
```

I want to use parameters to deduct an item from inventory. However when I run the query It does not deduct the correct amount, If I enter 2, it only deducts 1.

Also, when application starts I get the following error:

```
No mapping exists from DbType AnsiString to a Known SQLServer Compact data type.
```

I would like the new quantity to be the new amount on the Stocks field.

Comment: `The SQL SELECT statement returns a result set of records from one or more tables.`  it will not subtract or UPDATE a table

Comment: It sounds like there is an issue with your VB code as well, but you haven't shown us that.  As Plutonix suggests though, the major issue is that your SQL will retrieve data from the database and not make any changes at all.  If you want to update an existing record then an UPDATE statement is how you would do it